# Workflow Activity Timeout

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

We have a Automatic Workflow Activity which gets timeout sometimes and it stops the Workflow Process and end user doesn't notice it unless he is an workflow admin and has Workflow Admin View access.

We apply the workflow process on Bundles and this activity decides whether any item inside the bundle requires a translation. For this it loops through all the Components in the Bundle and check if any Component has a translatable field.

This usually works fine but throws the Timeout Exception sometimes. But If I re-starts it, it does complete the next second, Which is quite surprising for me. I don't know whether it caches in background somehow.

We are running on 2013 SP1 and below are the workflow setting in SDL Web Content Manager configuration

1. Number of threads for running automated scripts : **1**
2. Seconds before a time out error is generating when executing a Workflow script (0 for no timeout): **60**

I understand, if I increase the timeout value the issue could be fixed but as I mentioned when I restart the activity it is completed in a second and this is something worth considering.

Anyone has ideas about this behavior?

Is this because we are running on Single Thread and is not available for the activity.?

Would it help increasing the Thread Count? I believe it's thread safe but is there anything we should consider before doing this?

Comment: is there any correlation between, say, the number of fields / size of schema / size of bundle with the frequency of timeout (noting you say "_sometimes_")

Comment: I will try to figure out a pattern when this happens and update the question but why it is completed in a second when I restart the same activity, it is still a question.

Comment: That's an interesting observation Saurabh; I wonder if the error is triggered as the response took > 60 seconds but the processing is still undertaken in the background (and cached)... grasping at straws without having a set up to monitor/follow the underlying processes.

Comment: I've experienced similar workflow issues when adding hundreds of components to a bundle. As a test, are you ever able to recreate the problem with bundles containing up to maximum 30 components?

Answer (score -1):

I have experienced similar workflow issues in SDL Tridion SP1/SDL Web8.5. it`s product issue. Please create SDL ticket or contact sdl support for this issue.